# React native firebase how to assign value when getting data from db

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to assign var foo to a value within my firebase databse, however this just gives me undefined when using console log on foo.

```
var foo;
  firebase.database().ref(`/topics/lec1`).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
     foo = snapshot.val();

    console.log(foo); 

  });

   console.log(foo); //undefined
```

Comment: its undefined because you are not assigning it anywhere..

Comment: i've chahnged it, its still undefined

Comment: Just one question, is first console.log is also returning undefined? One inside the `then`? if not, then it's okay. You are logging foo before it is set by `firebase` since it is `asynchronous`

Comment: first you need to assign it, second its gonna be undefined outside `then()`, since firebase is asynchronous.

Comment: nope gives me the correct result

Comment: Then you should do whatever you want to do with inside the callback from `firebase`. second console.log is called even before you get response from firebase that's why its showing undefined

Comment: Yes you're correct/  it is first undefined then gives the correct result

Comment: @jimmy Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do whatever you want to do inside the callback

```
var foo;
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/topics/lec1`)
  .once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    foo = snapshot.val();
    displayValue();
  });

function displayValue() {
  //use value from firebase via foo.
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Comment: In React you'd typically call `setState(...)` from within `displayValue`, which will then trigger an update of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere are you assigning the foo variable. Try below:

```
  var foo;
      firebase.database().ref(`/topics/lec1`).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
         foo = snapshot.val();
     this.state.lec  = foo;
        console.log(foo); 

      });

       console.log(foo); //undefined
```

Comment: still  undefined

Comment: Instead of function() use a anonymous arrow function: () => {